# How to call a non static abstract method from another class

Tags: java, abstract-class

This is the header of  my abstract class

```
public abstract class RecursiveGo extends JFrame implements ActionListener
```

I want to take a method from this class, which is non static, and call it in the main method of the driver of this class. I have not yet made the driver, but I know that if I extend this class into the driver and make the driver a subclass it will come up with an error because I will not be overriding actionlistener. How can I call a non static method from this abstract class in a non abstract driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a useful non-static method that depends on a subset of the class (i.e. that doesn't depend on ActionListener), but the entire class has to stay abstract, it sounds like there's a clean line of separation there. Refactor the class to extract the subset, and make it available to your driver.

```
public abstract class RecursiveGo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

  private final UsefulSubset usefulSubset;

  public RecursiveGo() {
    usefulSubset = new UsefulSubset();
  }

  // Static, so you can address it as RecursiveGo.UsefulSubset.
  // Maybe it extends JFrame, too, and if made a top-level class
  // then RecursiveGo could further subclass the subset.
  public static class UsefulSubset {
    void methodCall {}
  }
}

class YourDriver {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    RecursiveGo.UsefulSubset instance = new RecursiveGo.UsefulSubset();
    instance.methodCall();
  }
}
```

Of course, maybe that useful subset could stand on its own as a top-level class, which would be even better. The code is malleable, and if it's not shaped the way you like, feel free to change the shape.

As ajb notes in the comments, see if making the method static would be worthwhile. Personally I favor dependency injection and mocking frameworks, so I'm not a fan of moving mountains to making methods static, but of course that would be a simple solution to your problem.

Comment: Or maybe the "non-static method" he's talking about calling doesn't refer to any instance fields and could actually be static.

Comment: @ajb Very true, but given that the OP specifically said "non static", who am I to contradict?

Comment: Wait how is a class declaration: public static class UsefulSubset { occuring in the class RecursiveGo?

Comment: It's a matter of style; you can certainly put the factored-out class _adjacent to_ rather than _inside of_ your RecursiveGo. If a class inside another class is `static`, it is called a "static nested class" and is there for organization only. If it isn't, then it's called an "inner class" and belongs to exactly one instance of the outer class. Static nested classes can be made private, and are great for hiding implementation details. [Find out more here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: private final UsefulSubset usefulSubset; is coming up with the error that there is no such symbol. What do I do?

Comment: @user3224584 The name `UsefulSubset` was picked arbitrarily. Make sure that you've created a new class that contains the functionality you want, name it well, and then create a field with that type.

Comment: also, when I call the void method I want: showBoard, I get an error saying there is no return type. I am trying to call up a method that constructs a gui, not one that returns a value.

Comment: @user3224584 I think those problems are outside the scope of your original question, and have to do with syntax instead. In any case, I don't think a useful answer would fit into this comments field. I encourage you to use the Code Review board or the Java chat room for further specific help with your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of RecursiveGo inside its driver that shall be the instance of its driver(sub class) ,as we cant instantiate the instance of abstract class. Then call that non static method of created object and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: by create instance i presume you mean do this: RecursiveGo g = new RecursiveGo(); when I do this, I get an error because it says you cant instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: Are you creating this instance inside the sub class of RecursiveGo ?

Comment: I cannot make the driver a subclass because I am not able to override the actionlistener method (meaning the subclass would have to be abstract as well). Therefore, I cant make an instance of the class (unless you know how I can override actionlistener while maintaining its function). I need to figure out how to call a nonstatic method in a main method in an abstract class if you want me to make my driver a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You technically can't do what you are asking within Java. Since a class that implements an interface MUST define the methods in that interface, you have to either define that method, or think of another way to do what you are trying to do altogether. For example you could try having the RecursiveGo not implement ActionListener, and then extend RecursiveGo, and then to still have an ActionListener - you would use a provided default ActionListener (if one exists).